# Error while parsing string to integer in jLabel

Tags: java, swing

I added `DocumentFilter` to `jTextField1` to retain only digits in the method `JTextFieldFilter()`.

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                   
    Document document = jTextField1.getDocument();
    document.addDocumentListener(new JButtonStateController(MultiPlayerGoButton, 0));
    ((AbstractDocument) jTextField1.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new JTextFieldFilter(1, 1));
    if(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()) == 2) {
        // code
    }
}
```

When I parsed the string in `jTextField1` to int and compared it with 2, I got an error,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt
    at Project.jTextField1KeyTyped
    at Project.access$2100
    at Project$20.keyTyped
```

I also tried string comparing, like `jTextField1.getText().equals("2")`

Comment: Your error says that your string is empty. You need to handle that use case, possibly by first checking that the string has a value and if not setting to zero.

Comment: The error is telling you *exactly* what is wrong: you're trying to parse as a number an empty String, and to solve this your parsing code needs to check for and account for an empty text field.

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener` on text components, use a `DocumentListener` instead

Comment: The filter I added is to limit the input to 1 digit.
So, as soon as I type something, it should filter it out and return back to `if-statement`. Consider I type 2, filter doesn't do anything, so `return` is 2, although showing textfield is empty. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: A much better way to create a JTextField which takes numeric input is `new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())`.  The resulting JFormattedTextField will return a Number from its `getValue()` method.

Comment: Get rid of the KeyListener!!! The point of using a DocumentFilter is to add the filter to the Document when you create the text field, Not when a key is typed. If you add the filter when the key is typed, then you just end up creating a new filter every time.

Comment: *"`jTextField1` to retain only digits"* Ugh.. offer the user a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` to make their lives easier.

Answer (score 1):

The raised exception actually told what was wrong:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Your JLabel is empty, hence causing the `NumberFormatException` when you try to parse it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the textfield is valued with an empty String : `""`.  That is of course not convertible to an integer.

Beyond this obvious thing, the `DocumentFilter` that you use (`JTextFieldFilter`) is probably incorrectly implemented if it removes the numeric characters of the textfield.
Besides, in any case, using a  `DocumentFilter`  doesn't relieve you to check if the textfield has some content or not.

So this check if unavoidable :

```
if(!jTextField1.getText().isEmpty) {
   ...
    // With a correctly implemented `DocumentFilter`, you should have a number here
    if (Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()) == 2) {
      ...
    }

}
```

Comment: `JTextFieldFilter` is correctly implemented, just that I need to input twice to get that if-statement working. I set the character limit to 1 in filter. @davidxxx